# network_security_group_id not expected in azurerm_network_interface

Tags: terraform, azure-devops, azure

I'm following a lecture on terraform for azure. They add a property network_security_group_id to an azurerm_network_interface

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "demo-instance" {
    name                        = "${var.prefix}-instance1"
    location                    = var.location
    resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.demo.name
    network_security_group_id   = azurerm_network_security_group.allow-ssh.id

    ip_configuration {
      .....
    }
}
```

But 'terraform plan' spits out

> Error: Unsupported argument │ │   on instance.tf line 43, in resource
> "azurerm_network_interface" "demo-instance": │   43:
> network_security_group_id   =
> azurerm_network_security_group.allow-ssh.id │ │ An argument named
> "network_security_group_id" is not expected here.

I'm guessing that this has moved somewhere else in some version, but I can't find the setting in the docs anywhere.

Where does network_security_group_id belong?

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "allow-ssh" {
    name                    = "${var.prefix}-allow-ssh"
    location                = var.location
    resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.demo.name

    security_rule {
        name                    = "SSH"
        priority                = 1001
        direction               = "Inbound"
        access                  = "Allow"
        protocol                = "Tcp"
        source_port_range       = "*"
        destination_port_range  = var.ssh-source-address
        destination_address_prefix  = "*"
    }
}
```

Just removing these resources and settings and it works anyway. The resources get created and I'm able to login with a key. So is this not needed anymore at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, this has changed at some point.

What's needed is a network_security_group_association which relates to a subnet_id and a network_security_group_id (the one that was in the network_security_group before)

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-internal-1" {
  name                 = "${var.prefix}-internal-1"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.geofriends.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vn.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "allow-ssh" {
   name                    = "${var.prefix}-allow-ssh"
   location                = var.location
   resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.geofriends.name

   security_rule {
       name                    = "SSH"
       priority                = 1001
       direction               = "Inbound"
       access                  = "Allow"
       protocol                = "Tcp"
       source_port_range       = var.ssh-source-address
       destination_port_range       = var.ssh-destination-address
       source_address_prefix        = var.ssh-source-address
       destination_address_prefix   = var.ssh-destination-address
   }
} 

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "sec-group-association" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet-internal-1.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.allow-ssh.id
}
```

Now the subnet subnet-internal-1 contains the allow ssh security_group